# How to apply different manipulations at different areas of an image in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have an image feed where I want so apply different color corrections at different areas of the images. Masks are helping here to apply individual manipulations just in masked areas. But how do I merge the differently manipulated images afterwards again?

Notice that the involved masks would not have sharp edges. So simply cutting out masked areas and stitching them together again would not be an option.

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, sometimes answers are quite trivial....

Not sure whether there are also some cases where other mechanisms are required. But mostly the different manipulations should not be applied in parallel, but one after each other. This eliminates the need to merge multiple images.